# How to remove Oracle Instant Client 19.6 on Ubuntu

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, client, sqlplus, instantclient

So i'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and trying to install Oracle SQL*Plus. I googled it and found [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html), I installed it using [this tutorial](https://www.foxinfotech.in/2019/03/how-to-install-sqlplus-in-linux-ubuntu.html)(install rpm package using alien). Following that tutorial i have installed this :

- oracle-instantclient*-basic-*.rpm
- oracle-instantclient*-sqlplus-*.rpm
- oracle-instantclient*-devel-*.rpm

Installation success but cant get it run (Can't login, i think because it's need oracle database installed, and i dont have one, i know i'm so stupid). So i install Oracle Database 11g Express Edition (I'm not installing the latest one because i follow this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9czrtHIfEA&t=199s)), success. Later i know Oracle Database 11g EX come with sqlplus too. So i have two sqlplus (from Oracle Instant Client 19.6 and Oracle Database 11g EX).

So, how to remove Oracle Instant Client 19.6?

Comment: Aside from removing instant client, you need to know that oracle database was not written to run on the branch of linux from which ubuntu is derived.  All attempts to get it to work on ubuntu are hacks, and every problem you face going forward will be shadowed by that fact.  My personal PC is also ubuntu, and here's what I do - Install Oracle Virtual Box. Then use that to create a vm and install Oracle Linux, which is derived from rhel, and install oracle on that.  With that you could actually leave the instance client on the host ubuntu.

Comment: Either you could use virtual box as @EdStevens suggested, or better, you could install `Docker` and then create a `database container`. Here is a list of images provided by Oracle https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/

Comment: See [Oracle database on Docker container](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2017/12/29/docker-oracle-12c-ee-on-ol7/)

Comment: Thanks! @LalitKumarB I'm installing docker and pull image from docker hub, it run perfectly.